# MVC 2 Contact Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How do I create a contact form that will submit to an email address?  The email account will be hard coded and grabbed from a form field to cc sender.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the form to submit to a controller action on the server (I'm assuming ASP .NET MVC 2 based on the question's title) which will build and send the email.

There are [plenty of tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=sending+email+from+c%23+.net) on how to actually send the email.  Basically, you use the mail objects from `System.Net` to construct a message and send it to an SMTP server.  Naturally, this means you'll need an SMTP server you can use.  Your email provider may or may not have a public one.  If not, that's a whole other question.